# SAR / syssstat issues

Tags: centos, troubleshooting, snmp, sar, sysstat

I am having issues with SAR not populating daily logs from the 10 minute interval runs it is supposed to be doing. I have the same configuration on multiple servers, and they are running sar just fine. Here is an example of the setup:

-CentOS 6
-sysstat 9.0.4

```
# sysstat-9.0.4 configuration file.
# How long to keep log files (in days).
# If value is greater than 28, then log files are kept in
# multiple directories, one for each month.
HISTORY=28
# Compress (using gzip or bzip2) sa and sar files older than (in days):
COMPRESSAFTER=31
# Parameters for the system activity data collector (see sadc manual page)
# which are used for the generation of log files.
SADC_OPTIONS="-S DISK"
# Compression program to use.
ZIP="bzip2"


# cat /etc/crond./sysstat
# Run system activity accounting tool every 10 minutes
*/5 * * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1
# 0 * * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 600 6 &
# Generate a daily summary of process accounting at 23:53
53 23 * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa2 -A
```

This is the output of files from a working server, as it should look:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 784968 Aug  1 23:55 sa01
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 703111 Aug  2 23:53 sar02
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 785016 Aug  2 23:55 sa02
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 685031 Aug  3 23:53 sar03
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 761928 Aug  3 23:55 sa03
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 711740 Aug  4 22:20 sa04
```

This is the output from the problem server (these files are also miniscule with no info):

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 504 Dec 21  2020 sa21
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 504 Oct 20  2021 sa20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 504 Jul 14 21:11 sa14
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 504 Jul 26 20:53 sa26
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 504 Aug  4 22:04 sa04
```

I have also tried stopping/starting sysstat and killing the pid for /usr/local/netsnmp/netsnmp_base/sbin/snmpd.  Nothing seems to be working. Any help would be greatly apprecaited!

Comment: `snmpd` has *nothing* to do with `sar`. Please check the `crontab` (typically), or maybe it's a systemd timer these days. On "*Nothing seems to be working. *": You seem to have no exact plan, right?

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing sysstat fixed the issue.

Comment: It is unclear what the issue is that this solved, i.e. what it was that was actually wrong and that gave rise to the problem with the logs.